# How can I redirect the user after an amount of time using PHP and codeigniter?

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I have a page that I want to load and display for an amount of time. The user should then be redirected back to the index view.

The code below is my controller.

```php
function send()
{
    $data = array(
        'author' => $_POST['author'],
        'header' => $_POST['header'],
        'paragraph' => $_POST['paragraph']
    );

    $result = $this->database_model->insert_into_articles($data);

    if( $result )
    {

        $view['content'] = "articles_send_view";
            $this->load->view('includes/template',$view );

    }

}
```

The following is my view.

```
<div id="content">
<div id='other_content'>
<p>
    article sent thanks 
</p>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what's being asked. Are you asking for the page load to be delayed? Are you asking how to redirect?

Comment: You need to look at ajax calls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe this can be done with PHP alone. You have two options in HTML.

A `<meta http-equiv="refresh">` tag in your `<head>` can be used to reload or redirect the user after a specified number of seconds. [Wikipedia has a couple of examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh):

> Place inside `<head>` to refresh page after 5 seconds:
>
> ```
> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
> ```
>
> Redirect to `http://example.com/` after 5 seconds:
>
> ```
> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/">
> ```
>
> Redirect to `http://example.com/` immediately:
>
> ```
> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">
> ```

The other option is to use JavaScript to redirect the user. You can do this by modifying [the `window.location` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.location), using [the `setTimeout` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout) to delay the call for, for example, five seconds (5000 miliseconds).

```
var redirect = function() {
    window.location = "/index.html";
};

setTimeout(redirect, 5000);
```

The `<meta>` redirect should work for almost all visitors, while the JavaScript won't work if they have JavaScript disabled. However, these don't conflict in any way so you could just include both on your page to be safe.